# Como calcular os valores de uma função em um intervalo todo sendo conhecidos só os valores nos pontos inteiros?

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

alguém pode me ajudar, por gentileza?

Estou tentando escrever uma função em Python (uso o 3) que implemente o seguinte código que está em Mathematica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:[https://rip94550.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/n-6-scaling-functions-and-mother-wavelets/]

Basicamente, o problema é o seguinte: preciso determinar uma função phi(t) sobre o intervalo [0,5] dadas as seguintes condições:

a) phi(0), phi(1), phi(2), phi(3), phi(4) e phi(5) são conhecidos.

b) constantes k0, k1, k2, k3, k4 e k5 reais também são conhecidas.

b) a função phi(t) é definida de modo recursivo:

phi(t) = sum(ki*phi(2t-i)) = k0*phi(2t) + k1*phi(2t-1) + k2*phi(2t-2) + k3*phi(2t-3) + k4*phi(2t-4) + k5*phi(2t-5)

Tentei usar o módulo sympy criando um polinômio que representasse phi(t):

```
def phi(h,t):
    norm = math.sqrt(2)
    string = '0 +'
    for k in range(len(h)):
        parameter = norm*h[k]
        string_aux = f'({parameter}*phi[2*t-{k}])+'
        string = string + string_aux
    string = string[:-1]
    pol1 = sym.sympify(string)
```

em que h é o conjunto de parâmetros que coloquei acima (item b).

Quando o executo entrando com a variável "t" declarada anteriormente usando

```
t = sympy.symbols('t')
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable
```

Não sei se este é o melhor caminho para implementar essa função porque ela ainda é recursiva. Podem me ajudar quanto a esse erro e quanto à uma boa implementação deste problema? Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Reveja a indentação da função `phi()`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques em meu código ela está identada. Obrigado pela observação. Vou corrigir aqui. Abraços.

Comment: Corrija, pois assim como eu fiz outra pessoa pode olhar a indentação e recomendar o fechamento da pergunta. Estou retirando minha recomendação assim que for feita a edicão.

Comment: @AugustoVasques correção feita! Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não encontrei essa linha `t = sympy.symbols('t')` dentro da função `phi()`. Pergunto você está tentando criar um simbolo sobre um parâmetro local da função em um escopo exterior ao da função? Se for não tem como, aquele parâmetro `t` só pode ser acessado dentro do corpo da função.

Comment: @AugustoVasques é isso mesmo. Eu estou tentando criar fora da função. Em geral essa variável t vai aparecer em outras funções também que estou criando. Pelo que você está me dizendo para cada uma delas eu preciso declarar internamente, correto? Vou tentar fazer isso aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques inclui a linha `t = sympy.symbols( ' t ' )` entre a última e penúltima linha mas o erro não se alterou. Continua idêntico.

Comment: O erro não é na linha `t = sympy.symbols('t')`. O erro está acontecendo na linha `pol1 = sym.sympify(string) ` tem algo de errado na expressão gerada `0 +(0.0*phi[2*t-0])+(1.4142135623730951*phi[2*t-1])+(2.8284271247461903*phi[2*t-2])`

Comment: @AugustoVasques vou pensar um pouco mais sobre essa linha. Grato. EDIT: Uma coisa eu já achei. A linha que define `pol1 = sym.sympify(string) tem algo de errado na expressão gerada 0 +(0.0*phi[2*t-0])+(1.4142135623730951*phi[2*t-1])+(2.8284271247461903*phi[2*t-2])...` está errada. Não devo usar colchetes. Devo usar parênteses. Editando em minha pergunta...